# Winter Driving in Minnesota: Can lowering a car improve how it handles in on icy / snowy / slippery roads?

Tags: winter, handling

I own two cars that handle very differently. When driving my 2001 Jetta, I can take sharp turns and not feel as much of the force, for example. However, my 2000 Hyundai accent feels higher and I feel the force of the turns. Its also a terrible winter vehicle and feels like a hockey puck sometimes (had it for 10 years). I plan on getting winter tires soon which should help a great deal, but I have been wondering if lowering the center of gravity might help. Am I right? Would I notice a difference? If so, how would you do it?

Comment: Not if it starts rubbing on the snow...

Comment: Really hard to compare vehicles like that. A 5 degree turn of the steering which can result in different wheel turn. More turn may feel less in control. Thickness of tires too. Lower to much you could become a sled with wheels off the snow

Comment: @Chris Where I live, most people never have to drive in high amounts of snow since the plows work pretty quick. The battle becomes a battle of traction with what's left on the roads after the plows run through (black ice, slippery patches, snow that's left on the ground etc) .

Comment: If you lower it enough, you can have a bobsled.

Comment: @JohnCanon That could be fun! lol :)

Comment: No but lowering your tire pressure to 15lbs will.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ride height won't have a big effect unless you drive curves with high velocity, something that is always troublesome on bad road conditions.

Adjusting the ride height is difficult and causes other issues. Easier and much more effective measures are good winter tires, defensive driving and experience. Should you prioritize handling on snow get the most narrow tires you can fit. Wider tires, often praised for their good grip on dry road, have worse grip on adverse conditions.
Also, snow chains when applicable

Comment: Snow tires are no help on icy roads.